# SQL Server 2005 Selecting last know good data

Tags: sql-server-2005, null, case

I have a situation where we collect capacity information in a table, but sometimes are data collections fail and no data is present for that day. I am trying to devise a way to check when a day is NULL, and then go back and get the `MAX(Date)` with good data. I know I am not providing a lot of information, but I have an idea to do it with a CASE statement, but I wanted to see if there were other ideas that I might not have thought of.

Thanks.

Comment: To rephrase the question, a table should have contiguous values in a date field but does not and you would like to find the last value before a gap?

Comment: Would you please provide the structure of your data...

Comment: Can't you order the date and select the first date. Use that date as a sub-query of the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps....

```
SELECT MAX(Date) FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE [DAY_FIELD] IS NOT NULL
```

Not sure of your requirements.

Comment: Yes, that would give me a unique query, but in this case I am inside a query running look at a row, and need to research back in time on the table to find the last time a good value existed and then fill it in for that date.